# add TableView subview crashes app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to add a tableview so when someone press a certain button, the view would switch into tableview with a few choices.

Here is my code for the button:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender  
    {
         LevelChoice *level = [[LevelChoice alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
         [self.view addSubview:level.view];
         [level release];   
   }
```

Here are code snap from my subclass of UITableViewController:

**LevelChoice.h**
Code:

```
@interface LevelChoice : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *choices; 
}
```

**LevelChoice.m**

Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    choices = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Level 1", @"Level 2", @"Level 3", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    return 3;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

     }
  cell.text = [choices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;

}
```

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: Try removing this code [level release]; and see if it works.

Comment: I think robin has got it right, don't release controllers. Also to present a tableview you have to retain the controller for it. So you can present the controller as a modalview and you can release it too. But since you are just presenting the view the application crashes.

Comment: What does the error message look like?

Comment: Whats the crash report you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinguish between Controllers and Views. You can

1. either present the `UITableViewController` with `presentModalViewController:animated:` or with `pushViewController:animated:`. (Yes, in this case you can release it.)
2. or just keep a `UITableView` in your existing view controller and show or hide it as necessary with the `hidden` property. Of course you need to implement the `datasource` and `delegate` methods for the table.